# INSERT python list into MySQL DB

Tags: python, database, list, insert, raw-input

I got some code but not really getting it working

```
listdata = [1, 2]
listdata1.insert(1, raw_input("Enter first thing into DB: ")
listdata2.insert(2, raw_input("Enter second thing into DB: ")
```

Then I make the DB, then

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testdb (TABLE, TABLE) VALUES (%s, %s)", (listdata1, listdata2
```

Which gives me:
NameError: name 'listdata1' is not defined

Is inserting this even possible this way? Or how could I get it to work?

Comment: You're trying to insert entries into the lists listdata1 and listdata2, which don't exist. Why are you using this particular data structure instead of variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem happens here:

```
listdata1.insert(1, raw_input("Enter first thing into DB: ")
```

You did not define the variable `listdata1` yet. Change it to listdata and you will fix the NameError.

Besides, you can append instead of insert e.g.

`listdata.append( raw_input("Enter first thing into DB: ") )`

Then the raw input will then be kept in position **0** in listdata, and you can retrieve it by `listdata[0]`

The sql looks wrong too ('TABLE' appear twice)